# New Apple ID and iCloud

Tags: macos, icloud, photos, apple-id

I created a new Apple ID on my Mac mini, but the "photos" preference, when checked asks for a password to the old account.

I can’t see where to enter my new Apple ID.

Since I don't remember the old password, how do I fix this?

Comment: Welcome to Ask Different. Be careful when you sign out of the old account - if you don’t have the original photos downloaded to the Mac or backed up, you could lose access to the old originals if they are only in the iCloud for the old ID.

Comment: Welcome to Ask Different! :)  I hope you come to find this site has a lot to offer! In case you haven't already, it's worth taking the time to read the [tour](https://apple.stackexchange.com/tour). All the best!